# Slow SQL Updates within a Cursor

Tags: sql, sql-server, performance, t-sql

I've added a new column, `packageNo`, to my table:

```
 create table Packages(
  id varchar(20) primary key,  -- ok, I know :)
  orderNo uniqueIdentifier not null,
  orderlineNo int not null, 
  packageNo int not null default(0)
)
```

Now I want to generate the `packageNo` with the following rules:

  reset it for each order

  ascendantfor order, orderline

My problem is that the script I wrote uses 15 minutes for 26500 rows on my testServer. 
Here it is:

```
set NoCount ON
declare @Counter int
declare @handledCounter int
declare @currentorder uniqueIdentifier
declare @fetchedOrder uniqueIdentifier
declare @fetchedId varchar(20) -- will using PK speed up things?

declare PackageNo_Cursor cursor  for 
  select orderNo, id from packages order by orderNo, orderlineNo for update of packageNo

open PackageNo_Cursor
fetch next from PackageNo_Cursor into @fetchedOrder, @fetchedId 

set @currentOrder = @fetchedOrder
set @counter = 0
set @handledCounter = 0
while @@fetch_status = 0
 begin 
     if (@currentOrder <> @fetchedOrder)
       begin  -- reset counter for each order
        set @currentOrder = @fetchedOrder
        set @counter = 0
       end
     set @counter = @counter + 1
     set @handledCounter = @handledCounter +1
     if (@handledCounter % 50 = 0)
      begin
        print 'handled = ' + cast(@handledCounter as varchar) 
      end
   update packages set packageNo = @counter where current of PackageNo_Cursor    
     fetch next from PackageNo_Cursor into @fetchedOrder, @fetchedId 
  end

close PackageNo_Cursor
deallocate PackageNo_Cursor
```

This should result in:

```
id   - orderno - lineNo - packageNo (what I need to set)  
ean1 - guid1   - 1      - 1  
ean2 - guid1   - 2      - 2   
ean3 - guid2   - 1      - 1  
ean15- guid2   - 3      - 2  
ean15- guid2   - 4      - 3
```

Can I make this run any faster?

Comment: Are you especially concerned about printing out every 50th package you've handled?

Comment: not really, I used it to check that something was happening and to see that the time consumption was linear.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You don't want to use a cursor, you want to do this as a set, like so:

```
update p set
    packageNo = r.packageNo
from
    packages p
    inner join 
      (select orderNo, orderLineNo, 
       ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY orderNo ORDER BY orderLineNo) as packageNo
       from packages) r on
        p.orderNo = r.orderNo
        and p.orderLineNo = r.orderLineNo
```

This will leverage SQL Server's [`ROW_NUMBER`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186734.aspx) function to get you the correct count by each line. Using `UPDATE...FROM`, we can create an `inner join` from which to update. This is vastly more efficient than the cursor.

See, cursors add an iterative ability to a procedural and set based language (SQL). The two don't play well together. That `update` statement is being called in order for each row (and opening/committing a transaction, to boot). If you do it all in one statement, SQL can parallelize this to make it much faster.

The standard rule is this: **Use cursors as sparingly as possible.** There are some fringe cases where they're necessary, but if you aren't doing massive amounts of SQL administration a day, it's doubtful you'll ever come across those cases.

Comment: this will work but it will be also slow because for each row in package you will need to execute select count(*) separately... this will require O^2 operations...

Comment: Hi Eric,
Thanks for your solution witch solve the update in 15s :-)

Comment: 15s still seems high a bit high for your record count. What indexes do you have on the table?

Answer (score 1):

Something like, not tested

```
update
    p
set
    packageNo = p2.Ranking
from
    packages p
    JOIN
    (SELECT
        orderNo, orderlineNo,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY orderNo ORDER BY orderlineNo) AS Ranking
    FROM
        packages) p2 ON p.orderNo = p2.orderNo AND p.orderlineNo= p2.orderlineNo
```

Comment: Thanks gbn,
this works well (15s).
it is the same solution that bogdan

Answer (score 0):

```
WITH cteA AS (
    SELECT 
        packageNo, 
        row_number() over (partition by orderNo order by orderNo, orderlineNo) rn
    FROM packages
)

UPDATE cteA
SET packageNo = rn - 1;
```

You should also create a clustered index on orderNo, orderlineNo.

(i hope you are using sql2005 or newer)

Comment: Hi
>(i hope you are using sql2005 or newer)
I actually do for this app :) but we still have apps running on sqlserver200 (and even some sybase 5.something!)
--
Dom

Answer (score -1):

In case you really need to use cursors, define your cursor with some attributes, like this :

```
DECLARE _cursor CURSOR LOCAL FAST_FORWARD FOR
....
```

Comment: this will confilict with the "for Update" (or any update of current)